# Cooking sous vide a steak which was vac pac frozen

Tags: sous-vide, vacuum, thawing

I bought a nice 1.5 inch New York cut steak from a butcher some time ago, and without thinking I vac packed it and froze it without spices. I feel like trying to cook it with my Anova tomorrow, so I took it out of the freezer and placed it in fridge instead. I am just a bit worried if I am doing the right thing here - my plan is to wait for it to thaw, take it out of the vac bag, apply salt and vac pack it again (maybe with a rosemary branch?) to sous vide it.

1. Is it ok to allow it to thaw in fridge for 1-2 days (unopened)?
2. Is it ok to let it thaw and then repack it and sous vide it straight away? Will that raise any risk of any bacterial growth (botulin etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can allow the steak to thaw in the refrigerator.  You can also repackage prior to cooking.  A third option is to cook sous vide from the frozen state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In fact the proper way to defrost all meats would be in the refrigerator NOT on a counter.

But do NOT defrost then thaw then freeze again.